# How to add pictures and links to a WordPress theme footer?

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have this code that is used by the wordpress theme to show pictures and links in the footer but I can't find out how to actually add content. It should look like this footer with "envato, squarespace and so on.":

http://demo.powerthemes.club/themes/gorising/

Can someone tell me how to add the footer items?

Thank you very much, because I can't think any further how to do it!

```
<!-- sponsor logos -->
    <section class="box-section sponsors">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php
                            while( $query->have_posts() ):
                                $query->the_post();
                                $client_meta = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
                                $link = gorising_get_smeta( 'link', $client_meta, '' );
                        ?>
                                <!-- 1 -->
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="sponsor-logo text-center">
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ) ?>" target="_blank">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .1 -->
                        <?php 
                            endwhile;
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- .sponsor logos -->
```

Comment: In your AdminPanel somewhere? "Customize theme" or something? What's the name of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Open the post in the WordPress Admin Panel. You should be able to add images typically in the bottom right hand corner under "Featured Image"

Comment: How do you mean that exactly? I don't understand clearly what you mean what I should do. I want it for every page not only for one post.

Comment: It seems like the code above is iterating through blog posts and displaying.

Comment: Try adding a post. Within the post, add a featured image. Adding a featured image is done typically in the bottom right hand side.

Comment: I think I understand what you want. Adding footer items is typically done in footer.php within the themes folder. This file is located in wp-content/themes/gorising/footer.php.

Comment: In fact when I add a feature image I have a image that is shown as a preview on my pages but I don't understand what that has to do with my footer

Comment: See my comment above. Let me know if you have any issues finding this file.

Comment: I already found it the code I posted is copy pasted out of it

Comment: An image is added as follows: <img src="<<link to your image>>" /> where <<link to your image>> is the URL of your image. Typically, images are added to the Media Library inside WordPress.

Comment: A link is added as follows: <a href="<<your link here>>" >test link</a> where <<your link here>> is the URL you want to redirect to.

Comment: But it seems like there is already a functionality in the code I posted to do this without adding html code myself. The question is how to add it the "elegent" way.

Comment: The code you have above seems to be looping through and displaying blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about this, but I think that this theme is equipped with a footer widgets functionality, which means you don't need to go to the theme files.

In your dashboard, select 'Appearance,' then widgets.

There should be a section on the right called footer, footer widgets, or more than one of these. The list on the left includes all the different widget options you have, such as text, menus, html, etc. Drag and drop from the left to the right, then customize.

**Alternatively**

If your theme doesn't support widgets, then add your code right after

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Also, try setting a featured image for your posts, maybe that's what you need. (On any page, lower right corner has a box called featured image, set one and see what happens).